# How would you hyphenate mid break-in

Tags: grammar

Middle of a break-in is the intended meaning.

Mid break-in?
Mid-break-in?
Mid-breakin?

Comment: Why is this tagged grammar?  Spelling isn't about grammar; it's about writing, which is not part of the language.

Answer (score 1):

From [Pop Culture Florid, James P. Goss (2000)...](https://www.google.co.uk/books/edition/Pop_Culture_Florida/OVEk7QcEEKEC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22mid%20break%20in%22&pg=PA124&printsec=frontcover)

> *In the early morning of June 17, 1972, five Watergate “plumbers” were arrested **mid–break-in**. Four of the men were from Miami, three were native Cubans, and all had previously worked for the CIA.*

You'll find several more relevant instances returned by [this Google Books search.](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22mid%20break%20in%22) All the ones I looked at are punctuated the same way, which looks fine to me.